# Referencing of Web Service on .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I want to add WCF Service Reference to my project. It gives me the error `"there was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you entered a valid address"`.

I can set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true. In my service's `web.config`:

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

but it doesn't solve my problem?

Comment: it seems that the URL you enter is not correct - it doesn't answer with metadata... you need to find out the correct URL for metadata of your webservice...

Comment: Can you hit the URL in a browser?

Comment: as pointed by @MikeParkhill, copy and paste the service URL in browser address bar ad see if you are able to hit it. MOst probably there is something wrong with the URL which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The URL which added to Project is Wrong. Just run WebService and Copy the url from WebBrowser and added to the reference.

This error is only beacuse URL mismatching, either URL for WebService is Stopped or not exist.